# How to Achieve custom chart control like below in QML QT (Not QT Widget)?

Tags: qt, qml

[image]I want to achieve chart control like attached image in QT quick application using QML.

Comment: [ChartView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcharts-qmlchart-example.html)?

Comment: yes . Any sample code how we can achieve this ?